# play/stop audio files with buttons

Tags: javascript, html

I have a number of short audio files that I need to play onlick. Each button should only play its corresponding audio file, and stop and reset the audio when it is clicked again.

This is the code that I have so far. The play/stop function works, but the code only plays whichever file is listed closest to the bottom, no matter what button you click. I assume it has to do with something in the function and button IDs, but I haven't been able to figure it out on my own. Any help would be super appreciated! Thank you!!

[edit to add more]
I think i figured out a bit more, the button calls the function 'play' which is listed twice, so it only plays the most recent one. i think i need to get the function to have a list with all audio files in it...trying something out now...

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

<head>

</head>


<body>
<audio id="oink" src="sfx/1oink.mp3"></audio>
<button onClick="play()">oink</button>

<audio id="cluck" src="sfx/2chicken.mp3"></audio>
<button onClick="play()">cluck</button>

<script>
function play() {
    var audio = document.getElementById('oink');
    if (audio.paused) {
        audio.play();
    }else{
        audio.pause();
        audio.currentTime = 0
    }
}
</script>

<script>
function play() {
    var audio = document.getElementById('cluck');
    if (audio.paused) {
        audio.play();
    }else{
        audio.pause();
        audio.currentTime = 0
    }
}
</script>


</body>

</html>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have two play() functions, which JS can't tell the difference between. It's not going to recognize which play to call just based on the vicinity of your elements. So try:

```
<audio id="oink" src="sfx/1oink.mp3"></audio>
<button onClick="play('oink')">oink</button>
<audio id="cluck" src="sfx/2chicken.mp3"></audio>
<button onClick="play('cluck')">cluck</button>

<script>
function play(id) {
    var audio = document.getElementById(id);
    if (audio.paused) {
        audio.play();
    }else{
        audio.pause();
        audio.currentTime = 0
    }
}
</script>
```

Comment: Ahh, yes right after i posted i realized that was probably the problem. thanks for the solution!!

Answer (score 1):

I would say that you do not need to use `<audio>` elements. You can access audio API this way:

```
var sound1 = new Audio("sfx/1oink.mp3");
sound1.play();

var sound2 = new Audio("sfx/2chicken.mp3");
sound2.play();
```

Answer (score 0):

As far as I can see solution of your program is to make only one play function and then make two if statements like this:

```
//Sorry I know this is not exactly what you want
//but you can replace "input" with some function
//like "on mouse click buttonID" play sound
//I don't know html functions but this is what I think.

function play() {
  if(input == "cluck") var audio = document.getElementById('cluck');
  if(input == "oink") var audio = document.getElementById('oink');
  if (audio.paused) {
    audio.play();
  }else{
    audio.pause();
    audio.currentTime = 0
  }
}
```